# replacing one bitmap with second one canvas android

Tags: android, android-canvas

i want to make an application in that there is two bitmap, i want to remove image whenever i touch my finger or move my finger and second bitmap's part be shown will be shown & first image's part will be erased i have used following code but in that **both images are replacing** but i want to erase only first one, second will shown on erased area, ..can any body help me how to handle this

below is the code

```
public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "PaintView";
Bitmap Bitmap1, Bitmap2;
Bitmap Transparent;
Bitmap overlay;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;

// List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Paint paint = new Paint();

public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    Bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bear);
    Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.camel);
    Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    c2 = new Canvas();
    c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
    c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);


    paint.setAlpha(0);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, null);
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 50, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    X = (int) event.getX();
    Y = (int) event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
 }

class Point {
float x, y;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return x + ", " + y;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved that problem by

```
    public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "PaintView";
Bitmap Bitmap1, Bitmap2;
Bitmap Transparent;
Bitmap overlay;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
private boolean isTouched = false;

// List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Paint paint = new Paint();

public PaintView(Activity context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bear);
    Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.date);

    c2 = new Canvas();
    c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
      //        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
    c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);

    paint.setAlpha(0);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);




}

 private static Point getDisplaySize(final Display display) {
  final Point point = new Point();
   point.x = display.getWidth();
   point.y = display.getHeight();
  return point;
 }

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("onDraw");
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 50, paint);
    if(isTouched)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    isTouched = true;
    X = (int) event.getX();
    Y = (int) event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
 }

  class Point {
float x, y;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return x + ", " + y;
}
 }
```